# Why is there an ability to override non abstract methods of base class

Tags: python, php, c++, oop

C++, PHP, Python and other OOP languages allow to override non-abstract methods of base class.

However, this ability allow to violate Liskov substitution principle. Because in such case base class can not be substituted in program with a derived class without changing program behavior.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a derived class to have different behavior from the base?

Comment: I'll make a friendly wager: In C++ I'll create a class called `base` with method called "foo". Feel free to define any derived class you want, and pass it to some function that expects a pointer or a reference to the `base` class, and which will call its `foo` method. You can try whatever you want, but you will not override my call to my base class's `foo`, no matter what you'll try.

Comment: See here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/244773

Comment: Sometimes giving people the power to Git-R-Done also give people the power to shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: Its possible to violate LSP with pure virtual functions fairly easily: `class Base { virtual float mul ( float x, float y ) = 0; }; class Sub { float mul ( float x, float y ) { return x + y; } };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this ability allow to violate Liskov substitution principle. Because in such case base class can not be substituted in program with a derived class without changing program behavior.

This is an incorrect characterization of the Liskov substitution principle. To be correct, change "without changing program behavior" to "without changing the correctness of the result" (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for a reference). The idea is not that the behavior is unchanged, but that the changed behavior is correct for the object in question. Different objects may have different behaviors that are considered correct, hence the need to override the non-abstract method. In fact, replacing one object with another might *require* a change in program behavior in order for the result to be correct.

For example, think about clicking things on this web page. The thing you click corresponds to the object, while the click corresponds to a call to that object's `onClick` virtual function. What is the correct behavior in response to your click? It depends on the object. If the object is a link, the correct behavior is to open the link. If the object is this paragraph, the correct behavior is to ignore the click (assuming a simple click; a double-click might select a word). Different behaviors, but both are correct. It is correctness that the Liskov substitution principle calls for, and correctness might require program behavior to change depending on the object in question.